# Creating a Vector Class object in Java

Tags: java, enumeration

The Problem with this is it gives me an error message saying The type Vector is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments . However I need the argument types. Keep in mind that I'm new to java.

```
 package day7; 

 import java.util.*;



    public class Vector {

      public static void main(String args[]) {

              //Vector        //vec     //Vector throws the error. 
       public Vector<String> vec = new Vector<String>(50);

       Vector v = new Vector();

       //Adding elements to a vector 
       vec.addElement("Apple");
       vec.addElement("Orange");
       vec.addElement("Mango");
       vec.addElement("Fig");

        // check size and capacityIncrement
        System.out.println("Size is: "+vec.size());
        System.out.println("Default capacity increment is: "+vec.capacity());


       Enumeration en = vec.elements();
       System.out.println("\nElements are:");
       while(en.hasMoreElements())
           System.out.println(en.nextElement()+" ");
```

Comment: Like yassin said you can't name your class Vector. I will up vote the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class shouldn't be named `Vector`. Otherwise, the compiler will refer to it even if you're trying to use `java.util.Vector`.

One of the two following solutions :

### #1

*Change your class name*

```
public class MyVector {}
```

### #2

*Use the fully qualified class name*

```
java.util.Vector<String> v = new java.util.Vector<>();
```

Comment: Okay I got it. The class name was the problem because It was vector and I need that to create the vector. Thank you so much!! I was completely lost and tried everything. @Yassin Hajaj

Comment: @CassandraB You're welcome Cassandra. Don't hesitate on mark the answer as accepted to let others know it's answered. :)

Comment: Last question:  how could I Create a Vector object that can hold any type of object.

Comment: @CassandraB This is asking for trouble. I suggest you read this post, it answers the question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it