# Java collection Type mismatch: cannot convert from TreeSet to SortedSet

Tags: java, collections

```
package collection;

import java.util.*;

public class SortedSet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         SortedSet set = new TreeSet();

    }

}
```

It giving me following error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from TreeSet to SortedSet
```

Comment: Your class name is SortedSet, change to something else or use the fully qualified name java.util.SortedSet

Comment: This is exactly the same problem as here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37504327/creating-a-vector-class-object-in-java/37504355#37504355

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class name is also `SortedSet`, so it is hiding `java.util.SortedSet`. Either rename your class (the preferred option) or use the full name of the interface in your variable declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:
- change the name of class,
- change type of set to TreeSet like
    TreeSer set = new TreeSet();